# C# WPF DataGrid RowDetails not updating using MVVM Caliburn.Micro

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, caliburn.micro, rowdetailstemplate

Trying to update a "Details" `DataGrid` `RowDetailsTemplate` in a "People" `DataGrid`(Doing some crazy *Inception* stuff!).

The collection is being updated correctly with `NotifyOfPropertyChange()`, but it doesn't seem to update the row in the `DataGrid`.

The `Header` "Adress Info" is there in the `RowDetailsTemplate`, but no rows are showing up in that `DataGrid`.

Models:

```
public class PersonModel
{
  public string FirstName{ get; set; }
  public string LastName{ get; set; }
}

public class DetailsModel
{
  public string Address{ get; set; }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
private ObservableCollection<PersonModel> _people;
private ObservableCollection<PersonModel> People
    {
        get { return _people; }
        set 
        {
            _people = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => People);
        }
    }

private ObservableCollection<DetailsModel> _details;
private ObservableCollection<DetailsModel> Details
    {
        get { return _details; }
        set 
        {
            _details = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Details);
        }
    }

public void SetRowDetail(PeopleModel selectedPerson)
    {
        PeopleModel person = selectedPerson;

        DetailsModel detailInfo = new DetailsModel();
        detailInfo.address = GetAddr(person.AddressIndex);
            
        Details = new ObservableCollection<DetailsModel>() {detailInfo};
    }
```

View:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="People"
          Grid.Row="1"
          cm:Message.Attach="[Event MouseUp]=[Action SetRowDetail($this)]">
          <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBox Text="Person Details" />
                    <DataGrid x:Name="Details"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding TakeoutCoefficients}">
                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Address Info"
                                                Binding="{Binding Address, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                    </DataGrid>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
          </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
</DataGrid>
```

I would like to achieve this without having to take out the `RowDetailsTemplate`.

Tried BindableCollection and ItemsSource doesn't seem to help either.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Setup `ItemsSource` for `DataGrid`, bind it to the collection property, and use `ObservableCollection` as storage not `BindableCollection`

Comment: @aepot Thanks for the suggestions. I tried both, but doesn't fix anything for me. I've edited the question with your suggestions. Let me know if you had a different idea of how to solve this.

Comment: Where's `ItemsSource` for the parent `DataGrid`? e.g. `{Binding People}`. Why do you need embedded `DataGrid`?

Comment: Guessing that `Details` property must be inside of `PersonModel` and `PersonModel` can implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` (using your MVVM library). Then outer `DataGrid.ItemsSorce` may be bind to `People` and inner `DataGrid.ItemsSorce` to `Details`.

Comment: @aepot With `Caliburn.Micro` mvvm you can just have `x:Name` act like the `ItemsSource`. I need the embedded `DataGrid` because the real data I have has a lot more properties than the one I have here in the example. It will change based on what row is selected in the parent `DataGrid`.

Comment: Ah, ok. Billions of tangled frameworks. I'm pretty old and using pure WPF. :) You may move `Details` inside the `PersonModel` then. Embedded `DataGrid` will pick correct items on row change automatically because inside row `Binding` source (`DataContext`) is set to the selected row's item, not to parent VM. Child table doesn't see the property now.

Comment: @aepot I think you're right, I'm probably over complicating things by separating the 'details'.